# Load tableViewCell from Storyboard without using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I want to load a tableViewCell from the storyboard without using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to create a prototype cell to reference before cellForRowAtIndex is called. Calling that outside of CellForRowAtIndex does funny stuff.
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is still being used in cellForRowAtIndex as it normally has been.

I dynamically set the cell heights based on it's contents. This requires me to know where the size, positions, text attributes like font sizes, alignments, etc of views in the tableViewCell. Otherwise I have to hard code these values to match what's in the storyboard.

What I'm currently doing is create a new xib file with just the cell, load it from viewDidLoad, and keep a pointer to it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // typical coding stuff goes here 

    // load nib
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ContentTextCell" bundle:nil];

    // assign nib to identifier
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ContentTextCell"];

    // reference cell
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
    _referenceContentTextCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Is there any way for me to load the tableview cell without make it's own nib? Using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: causes the tableView to behave in an incorrect way.

Additional notes
I think a lot of people are under the impression I call the code on cellForRowAtIndex. It's called in viewDidLoad. It was always displayed as such but perhaps it was easy to understand when skimming the question. I also still use dequeueResuableCell as normal in cellForRowAtIndex. Just wanted to make that clear.

The row heights are dynamic. If you made the suggestion that I should make the row height 44 then you may want to read the question more carefully before attempting to answer the question.

The text I'm using is from a json file, it requires the paragraph, font and positioning of a textView to calculate the text height, which impacts the row height. I'd like to pull these pieces of data from the prototype cell rather then hard coding the values, and making sure they match what's in the storyboard.

The code already works as is. It runs fine. I just think it'd be more convenient to be able to pull the prototype cell from the storyboard rather than making a new xib for it.

Comment: You don't want to use this approach. I've tried it. When you finally get it working, it will be nonperformant and will block your main thread. When you put it on a background thread, it won't work because UIKit does not like being on a background thread. It's really clever, and it's a shame it doesn't work, but you're better off adding up string sizes and padding.

Comment: Just so that we're on the same page, you're saying that loading a nib, specifically a nib with one tableViewCell will block the mainthread?It's a small nib, if you open it in textedit it's less than a page. Did you think this code was in cellForRowAtIndex? That would be terrible but it's only in viewDidLoad. I don't think it blocks the main thread in any measurable span of time.

Comment: I'm not saying that loading the nib will be a problem.  I'm saying this: if you have an array of lots of data, and you iterate through each item in the array, and feed each item into your cell, and layout the items to calculate the height... this can block the main thread noticeably.

Comment: I see, that would hinder performance to a noticeable degree. But I don't iterate through the array. I directly index the data with the indexPath, O(1) time, for the text value to calculate the height on tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: The tableview will iterate through all of it, unless you implement `estimatedHeight…`, as was danh's suggestion.  My understanding (which I now think was wrong) is that you were iterating through all of the data objects, calculating their height, and caching them for later immediate return in `heightForRow…`.

Comment: You can't pull a UIView from a storyboard, but you can pull a UIViewController out.  You could make a dummy controller with just the cell as a subview if you'd rather use storyboards, but that's probably no less weird than your current approach.

Comment: Finally, I'm just curious, can you show me what "I don't iterate through the array. I directly index the data with the indexPath, O(1) time" looks like in code (maybe use pastebin or Gist or something)?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I started thinking about it and maybe there is some misunderstanding on my part by what was said about iterating through the array. When I say I don't iterate through it, I meant I never used nsarray enumerate, or use a for loop to go through the array. I use coredata so I fetch my first batch on viewDidLoad and it uses resultsController to get the next batch. I just said O(1) because I don't use any for loops. Anyways here's my code http://pastebin.com/mYt05EYZ hopefully it clears things up and doesn't cause your eyes to catch on fire. I run my app on an iPhone on a 4s and it hovers at 60fps.

Comment: Upon more reflection, if you meant by iterate through the array by indexing each item via indexPath whenever heightForRowAtIndexPath or viewForCellAtIndexPath then yes I iterate through it, but that's really dependent on the users scrolling right? So I don't really consider that iterating through the array. Anyways, that's a bunch on minutiae and I'm exposing my pedantic side so I'm going to shut up now. And thanks again for stimulating, thoughtful code talk.

Comment: In order to make the scroll bar the correct size, UITableView calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` on every item in your data source when it loads.  So if your tableview has lots and lots of rows, your main thread (and `_referenceContentTextCell`) will be busy for a while.  If there are no performance issues in your app then don't worry about it, but if down the road your UI starts to freeze when entering into this view, this code is the place to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the row height is a function of your model and some attributes of subviews in the cell, for example, a string from your model and the font size in the cell's text view.

I agree that keeping the view attributes of the cell's subviews in code seems redundant with keeping them in the storyboard, but you're also right that keeping a reference cell around is weird.  It's weird whether you get the cell from a nib or whether you find a way to get it from the storyboard (which I don't think you can, which is the answer to your stated question).

Dequeueing a cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath makes little more sense and probably causes an infinite recursive loop as I'm sure you've found.

So you probably won't love this answer, but I think best idea is "redundancy with an attitude change".  "Redundancy" means that you keep the view attributes in code, like a method that returns the textView's desired font pointSize.  "Attitude change", means you don't think of this as redundancy.  Instead, your code should be the authority on all of the view attributes pertinent to row height.  Think of the prototype cells in the storyboard as just a way of visualizing what the correct coded values should be.  I'd even recommend setting the attributes in code using the coded values when you configure the cell, especially if there aren't too many of them.

Finally, if your rowHeight calculation is elaborate, and it sounds like it is, be sure to also implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and do a much quicker calculation therein (like return a constant).

Comment: You are correct with your assertion about calling cellAtIndexPath from the tableview would cause some infinite recursion. You're the only one that understood my question. Calling dequeue just acts weird. I'll pass in index section 0 row 0 and the first row will be messed up. Perhaps it's a lack of clarity on my part. Blame me if you guys want. I understand what you mean with "redundancy with an attitude for change" the code is the authority on most things, with the exception of positioning/sizing and text attributes, which I think interface builder is much faster and efficient at doing.

Comment: In summary, the answer for loading prototype cells without dequeueForRowAtIndexPath is that you can't.

This is not for you danh but for any one else who was wondering the same thing I was. Thank you danh.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been working through an almost identical problem. You want the height, but the height depends on a bunch of the cell UI setup. It might even be a fairly simple task of checking the padding height above and below an image. Something which could get tweaked in IB several times before you are done so you don't want to duplicate the padding value in code, you want to check them  against the current values in IB.

You can call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` from anywhere (assuming you have a reference to the `UITableView`). So you don't need another way to get the cell. This will not cause recursion or infinite loop problems.

There is a catch though. The cell won't go back to the auto-reuse pool. A `UITableView` figures out which cells scroll off the screen and puts them in the pool, but this cell never goes onto the screen and so the table view never remove it from the screen and put it back in the pool. To make matters worse, the table still has a strong reference to it; so if you lose your reference, it's not going to get cleaned up, it's essentially leaked memory. You can't use it, the table view can't use it and it will stay in memory until the backing `UITableView` gets deallocated.

I found a few ways around problem:

1. Dequeue the cell once, store it someplace safe and use the same one every time you need to test out some cell formatting. You can even call `prepareForReuse:` to clean it up every time you want to test something new. Holding a single extra cell in memory is unlikely to be a killer for most apps.
2. Sneak it back into the re-use pool. Wait, what? Yeah, I said you can't do it, but you can, but the thought makes me cringe a little. Next time you get to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` don't dequeue a new cell, use the one you've got laying around and return that one instead. This will slip your wayward cell back into the fold and it will eventually make it's way back into the reuse pool.

So you can do this.... should you? Well, that's a different question. Apple has provided some alternatives to try and get around this issue, but in some cases they just don't work effectively.

Comment: What are those alternatives that Apple has provided? Could you provide som links please?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad pattern and you will start to get undesired behaviours which you have already seen some of. It might be better to store the `height` against the cell as a class method.

```
+ (CGFloat)requiredHeight;
{ 
  return 44.f;
}
```

and call it as such

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = [OKACell requiredHeight];
```

This does mean you need to manage the height in two places but because of the descriptive name  and class method it shouldn't be difficult to change when that time comes.

Comment: Have you tried that cell = [tableView dequeue...?  Pretty sure that the dequeue in heightForRowAtIndexPath will cause an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: Oliver, I think you misunderstand my question. I've written additional notes in my question. Though Danh has the most correct answer. Which is no. You can't load a prototype cell from the storyboard.

Comment: @Biclops, if your row height is dynamic you should use your model to decide the cell height, not the view. Its a good pattern to have model - view - controller seperation. You can use `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` to calculate how tall the cell should be in the tableView heightForRow delegate method.

Comment: I do but where would I get the font, width and lineBreakMode from? I should be getting them from the label/textview I'm going to be using, otherwise I would have to hardcode the values.